# Qemu: SEV: Failed to query the attestation report length ret=-22 fw_err=0 ()

Tags: remote-attestation, kvm, amd

I try to attest my vm running on a kvm+qemu host using `qmp` and this command:

```
echo '{ "execute": "qmp_capabilities" }\n{"execute":"query-sev-attestation-report","arguments":{"mnonce":"ZBaOEOsVmenc5q34VJb9jw=="}}' | socat - tcp:192.168.123.1:4444 | tail -1 | jq
```

This results in

```
{
 "error": {
   "class": "GenericError",
   "desc": "SEV: Failed to query the attestation report length ret=-22 fw_err=0 ()"
 }
}
```

No other logs are written, I checked that the guest runs on an SEV-enabled VM.What does this error mean and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attestation is only available in kernel version >= `5.12`, so after upgrading my Ubuntu from 20.04 with `5.4.0-125-generic` to 22.04 with `5.15.0-48-generic` it worked as aspected.